# Interrupting select, sleep and similar blocking functions inside a thread (pthreads). Signals in threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a server socket thread that accepts connections. It uses select with timeout 1 second in order to do other things. However sometimes I want to do these things right away when a specific signal comes to the application from **outside**. In a single thread program a signal interrupts sleep and timed IO blocking functions like select. However in a thread other than main signals do not interrupt sleep.

I can signal from main thread using pthread_kill() and the sleep is interrupted, but when the signal comes from outside it doesn't interrupt the sleep in thread. If I install a handler and inside the handler I call pthread_kill() to that thread the handler catches the signal and enters infinite loop.

**How do I interrupt the sleep by a signal from outside the program - for example SIGUSR1.**

I could do this workaround: I could start another thread to do the other things I do in the server thread. It would wait on a condition and then the main thread would signal the waiting thread on a signal. But I want to really want to know to interrupt sleep/select in other threads - for example for quicker shutdown I want to interrupt all waiting and let the threads quit a bit faster. Also I want to understand how signals work in other threads. And sometimes you want to interrupt a sleep that's not in your code (another library)

I read about pthread_sigmask(), but I'm not sure I understand it. In main thread handlers are installed to handle signals. What happens in other threads? [This example](https://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/pthread_sigmask.htm) uses sigwait() to receive signal. What happens if you don't call sigwait? Are signals accumulated in a queue or just they don't have an effect on a thread that doesn't wait for them?

Comment: Well, `select` waits on file handles. So create a pipe

Comment: Since you're already using an event loop, use `signalfd()` instead of a signal handler.

Comment: `signalfd()` might be a good way to interrupt the select, but I'm not just interested in this particular case. I want to  be able to be able to interrupt any blocking function that would otherwise be interrupted by a signal if it was in the main thread. I'm experimenting a bit. `pthread_kill()` does the job, but it is called from within the process. Maybe I can capture SIGUSR1 in main thread and then send SIGALRM to the thread I want to interrupt avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. I don't know if there is another solution. **I'll wait for suggestions.**

To signal that work needs to be done **SIGUSR1** is sent to the program. It sends SIGALERT to the threads to make them interrupt blocking code like sleep, select, etc. As a side effect blocking in main thread also gets interrupted, even though the signals are sent to the other threads only.

It can't be done with just one signal - like handle sigalert and then signal alert the two other threads using pthread_kill, because for it enters an endless loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h> // for errno
#include <pthread.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define nullptr NULL
typedef int bool;
#endif

// I copied this. I don't know why it's in a loop
#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
        do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

pthread_t t1;
pthread_t t2;
pthread_t st;
pthread_t mainThreadId; // main thread

void *workerThread(void * param);
void unblockSignals();
void alertSignaHlandler(int sigNum);
void installSignalHandler(int sigNum, __sighandler_t handler);

void sigUsr1Handler(int sigNum) {
  pthread_kill(t1, SIGALRM);
//  pthread_kill(t2, SIGALRM); // let's say we only want t1 to interrupt
}

// on SIGTERM we want all threads to interrupt sleep so they can quit faster
void sigTermHandler(int sigNum) {
  // setRunning(false); // also implement a global running vairable with a mutex, that other threads check to quit
  pthread_kill(t1, SIGALRM);
  pthread_kill(t2, SIGALRM);
//  pthread_kill(mainThreadId, SIGALRM); // main thread will be interrupted by the signal anyway.
}

void alertSignaHlandler(int sigNum) {}

int main() {
  void * ret1;
  void * ret2;

  mainThreadId = pthread_self();

  printf("main starting with pid %d\n", getpid());

  installSignalHandler(SIGALRM, alertSignaHlandler); // we need this to prevent program termination on alarm
  installSignalHandler(SIGUSR1, sigUsr1Handler); // send this signal to interrupt other threads
  installSignalHandler(SIGTERM, sigTermHandler);
  installSignalHandler(SIGINT, sigTermHandler);

  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &workerThread, (void *)1);
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &workerThread, (void *)2);

  // simulate work in main thread. Only interrupt this on SIGTERM or SIGINT (ctrl-c)
  time_t ts = time(NULL);
  sleep(20);
  ts = time(NULL) - ts;
  printf("main(): sleep took %lds\n", ts);


  pthread_join(t1, &ret1);
  pthread_join(t2, &ret2);

  printf("main thread reached end\n");

  return 0;
}

void *workerThread(void * param){
  long id = (long) param;

  printf("workerThread %d starting...\n", id);

  // in the real world this will be in a loop. somethign like this
  //  while(running) {
  //    // do something every minute
  //    doSomething();
  //    sleep(60); // this sleep we want to interrupt, because we don't want to wait 60 seconds to exit
  //  }

  time_t ts = time(NULL);
  sleep(60); // this can also be select, read or other timed blocking call.
  ts = time(NULL) - ts;
  printf("workerThread(%ld): sleep took %lds\n", id, ts);

  return NULL;
}

void installSignalHandler(int sigNum, __sighandler_t handler){
  struct sigaction newAction, oldAction;

  memset(&newAction, '\0', sizeof(newAction));
  newAction.sa_flags = 0;
  //newAction.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
  newAction.sa_handler = handler;
  sigaction(sigNum, &newAction, &oldAction);
}
```